# Error building Alljoyn Certification Test 15.09

Tags: android, alljoyn

I'm trying to build the certification apk for Alljoyn 15.09a. I've cloned the source from https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/compliance/tests and followed the instructions from chapter 5 in AllJoyn™ Validation Test User Guide. It has an error in the validation-tests-suites. The error message is:

```
Failed tests:
  ConfigTestSuiteTest.test_26_timedOutWaitingForSessionLost:1511->BaseTestSuiteTest.executeTestMethodFailsAssertion:67 No assertion failure, expecting assertionFailure with message: Timed out waiting for session to be lost
  ConfigTestSuiteTest.test_27_configurationNotRetainedOnRestart:1613->BaseTestSuiteTest.executeTestMethodFailsAssertion:73 expected:<[Received About announcement did not contain expected DeviceName expected:<[newD]eviceName> but was:<[d]]eviceName>> but was:<[Value for DeviceName retrieved from GetAboutData() does not match expected value expected:<deviceName> but was:<newD]eviceName>>
  ConfigTestSuiteTest.testConfig_v1_33FactoryResetNoUpdateConfiguratins:1752
mockServiceHelper.waitForNextDeviceAnnouncement(
<any>,
<any>,
<any>
);
Wanted 3 times:
-> at org.alljoyn.validation.testing.suites.config.ConfigTestSuiteTest.testConfig_v1_33FactoryResetNoUpdateConfiguratins(ConfigTestSuiteTest.java:1752)
But was 4 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at org.alljoyn.validation.testing.suites.config.ConfigTestSuite.waitForNextDeviceAnnouncement(ConfigTestSuite.java:181)

  ConfigTestSuiteTest.testConfig_v1_35FactoryResetResetsPasscode:1830
mockServiceHelper.waitForNextDeviceAnnouncement(
<any>,
<any>,
<any>
);
Wanted 4 times:
-> at org.alljoyn.validation.testing.suites.config.ConfigTestSuiteTest.testConfig_v1_35FactoryResetResetsPasscode(ConfigTestSuiteTest.java:1830)
But was 5 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at org.alljoyn.validation.testing.suites.config.ConfigTestSuite.waitForNextDeviceAnnouncement(ConfigTestSuite.java:181)

 ConfigTestSuiteManagerTest.getApplicableTests:86->validateValidationTestGroup:97->validateValidationTestItems:107 expected:<27> but was:<25>

Tests in error:  
  ConfigTestSuiteTest.test_27_timedOutWaitingForSessionLost:1587->BaseTestSuiteTest.executeTestMethodFailsAssertion:66->executeTestMethod:2394 » NullPointer

Tests run: 674, Failures: 5, Errors: 1, Skipped: 14
```

I've made sure I have the correct Maven and Java version. I've also tried 14.12 and getting the same issue, so I think my setup is wrong. Can anyone help me with compiling this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There is another document: AllSeen Alliance Self-Certification User Guide at https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/_media/compliance/allseen_self_certification_program_developer_guide_v5.doc.

It updates the final step to:

```
$ mvn clean install –Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dandroid.sdk.path=$ANDROID_SDK
```

which fixed my problem. So the steps I followed were

```
$ git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/compliance/tests
Copy the libraries listed in the README.txt in $VAL_DIR/java/components/validation-dependencies/libs to $VAL_DIR/java/components/validation-dependencies/libs 
$ cd tests/java/components/validation-base/HEAD/
$ mvn clean install
$ cd ../../validation-dependencies/HEAD/
$ mvn clean install
$ cd ../../validation-framework/HEAD/
$ mvn clean install
$ cd ../../validation-tests/HEAD/
$ mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dandroid.sdk.path=$ANDROID_SDK
```